# Add Like Button to website

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

I am trying to install the like button on my website but cannot get it to appear on the website.I have tried everything but no joy. I have pasted the codes etc. etc but nothing. I use Serif Webplus X2 for web design. 
I added the code to a html text box and after uploading to the web only the code print appears on the website but no button. However if I use the Facebook Platform code it works??

Comment: Got a link that shows the page where it is supposed to appear? That way we can look at the code and determine what might be the problem.

Comment: Play around with adding simple html code like <b>this is bold</b> so that it does render html rather than being displayed raw. Then add the iframe code and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, i found interesting information on this website

http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/04/adding-facebook-like-buttons-to-your-site-is-damn-easy/

More easy, Facebook generate the code for the button "I like" for any website.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: What in there did you find interesting? TLDR;

Answer (score 2):

Add the below HTML code on any page:

```
<iframe
    src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://www.facebook.com/NiraTechTraining?ref=ts&fref=ts"
    scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
    style="border:none; width:450px; height:80px">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get Your Code Here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

The easiest way is to use a "*iframe*".

Make a HTML block and paste it into the body (Click the 'Paste to Body' Button on top right)

**If it doesn't work in your preview, you have to Host it.**

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to upgrade, Serif WebPlus X6 and later versions include support for Facebook Like buttons. In X6, go to Insert->Social Media->Facebook Widget and select 'Like Button' from the drop-down.